# Hide/Show an image drawn with Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, show-hide, jcheckbox

I have multiple images drawn with Graphics. How can I make them appear and disappear using a JCheckBox ?

```
private void drawImages(int index) {
   Graphics g = mNew.getGraphics();
   int x = index % this.width;
   int y = index / this.width;
   g.drawImage(imageLabelPixel.get(idImage-1), x, y, 100, 100, null);
}
```

Comment: `if (JCheckBox.isChecked) drawImage();`

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] that we can copy-paste and see what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox();
ImgPanel p = new ImgPanel();

cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        if(cb.isSelected){
            p.set(0);
        } else {
            p.set(-1);
        }
    }
});
```

.

```
public class ImgPanel extends JPanel {

    private int i = 0;
    private List<BufferedImage> imgs;

    public ImgPanel(){
        //init imgs
    }

    public void set(){
        i = 0;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(i >= 0){
            Image img = imgs.get(i-1);
            Image img1 = img.getScaledInstance(100, 100, null);
        }

        g.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

You can't simply draw on a graphic and then hand it to a compoennt or so (I don't really understand what your given code should have done). Instead you have to overwrite the paintComponent method of a Component and put your custom drawing code in there.

Comment: In fact I have a long project with multiple functions and that's why I didn't poste them here. I have a Vector of BufferedImages and this function , drawImages, draws every image of the vector over another image (the background image). So what I'm trying to do is to make disappear all those images using a JCheckBox. I just want to see only the background image when JCheckBox is selected.

Comment: Then you may just make a ArrayList, which you save the state of the JCheckBoxes in, so that every index of the list will stand for the enabled state of one of your layers. In you drawImage you just have to proof the boolean saved for the given index and depending on that draw the image or don't. Edit: To find out when the state of the checkboxes changes, just add an ItemListener or an ActionListener to them.

Comment: Good to hear I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use graphics to draw something on the screen you want to remove. Graphics just renders it on the screen along with all the other graphics you have drawn, It doesn't keep track of components

Your options are to add an action event to your checkbox and repaint the screen from scratch not drawing the image, or to just use a `Label` to draw the image and set it to invisible when the box is checked